# Android studio changes for Realm Object Server migration from 2.x to 3.x

Tags: android, android-studio, realm, database-migration

I am an android developer, but new to Android Studio and Realm. I have a working app on `ROS 2.x` and android client with `realm-gradle-plugin 4.3.4`.   In my project I have a requirement for ROS migration from 2.x to 3.x. Can you help me find answers to following questions:

1) Is there a need to upgrade the android `gradleplugin/sdk` when the objective is just to upgrade the ROS?

2) If `sdk/plugin` needs to be upgraded, then what are the changes required to migrate client from current(realm-gradle-plugin 4.3.4) to requested version? Is there any documentation to refer?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you were using the Realm Sync Developer Edition then you're kinda screwed. But if you were using the on-site version of Realm Platform, then you can refer to https://docs.realm.io/sync/v/3.x/self-hosted/manage/upgrading#upgrading-from-ros-2-x-to-3-x and hope for the best

Comment: Thank you, will check and get back on this.